# Best way to locate data in nested arrays in swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, multidimensional-array, collections

Given data of nested objects like this:

```
struct Store{
    var name: String
    var items: [Item]
}
 

struct Item{
    var name: String
    var free: Bool
}
 

var dataSet = [
    Store(name: "firstStore", items: [
        Item(name: "item1", free: false), Item(name: "item2", free: false),   Item(name: "item3", free: true),
    ]),
    
    Store(name: "secStore", items: [
        Item(name: "item4", free: true), Item(name: "item5", free: false),   Item(name: "item6", free: true),
    ]),
    
    Store(name: "thiStore", items: [
        Item(name: "item7", free: false), Item(name: "item8", free: true),   Item(name: "item9", free: false),
    ]),
    
    Store(name: "lastStore", items: [
        Item(name: "item10", free: true), Item(name: "item11", free: false),   Item(name: "item12", free: true),
    ]),
]
```

By given a section (store) and a row (item) as a starting point I need to locate the next/previous item which fulfils some criteria (in this case being free). I will use IndexPath to notate the location. The methods should not only return the item but also the position (denoted by a IndexPath).

Here I what I got. It is working but surely there must be a better more clean way of archiving this.

```
func nextFree(from start: IndexPath) -> (Item, IndexPath)?{
    for (section, store) in dataSet.enumerated().dropFirst(start.section) {
        for (row, item) in store.items.enumerated().filter({$0.element.free}){
            if section == start.section && row <= start.row { continue }
            return (item, IndexPath(row: row, section: section))
        }
    }
    return nil
}
 

func previousFree(from start: IndexPath) -> (Item, IndexPath)?{
    for (section, store) in dataSet.enumerated().reversed(){
        if section > start.section { continue }
        for (row, item) in store.items.enumerated().reversed().filter({$0.element.free}){
            if section == start.section && row >= start.row { continue }
            return (item, IndexPath(row: row, section: section))
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

What would be the most clean and performant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift we are often tempted to use all the fancy features, and while it maybe good idea to take advantage of the super useful functions like `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, `zip`, etc. sometimes the simple solutions work the best for a given use case.

This will be obviously very opinionated answer, but this questions asks for answers of this nature, so here is mine.

I believe you are going the right way with a simple `for-loop` implementation. This improves readability and allows you to return fast once the result you were looking for was found. Here is slightly improved version, with `where` clause.

```swift
func nextFree(from start: IndexPath) -> (Item, IndexPath)? {
    let sections = dataSet.enumerated().dropFirst(start.section)
    for (section, store) in sections {
        let rows = store.items.enumerated().filter { $0.element.free }
        for (row, item) in rows where section != start.section || row > start.row {
            return (item, IndexPath(row: row, section: section))
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Other previously mentioned functions like `map`, `filter`, `reduce` wont give us the flexibility we need, and in this case the simple `for-loop` is very useful and easy to digest. The only thing apart adding the `where` clause is using a separate properties for the enumerated collections you are iterating over, since it will reduce the complexity while reading each life of code.

Similarly to `nextFree`, here is the `previousFree` function:

```swift
func previousFree(from start: IndexPath) -> (Item, IndexPath)? {
    let sectionsToDrop = (dataSet.count - 1) - start.section
    let sections = dataSet.dropLast(sectionsToDrop).enumerated().reversed()
    for (section, store) in sections {
        let rows = store.items.enumerated().reversed().filter { $0.element.free }
        for (row, item) in rows where section != start.section || row < start.row {
            return (item, IndexPath(row: row, section: section))
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your solution does improve both readability and performance slightly. Also I noticed to changed some naming thus keeping it consistent.  Also since your solution is so similar to mine it tells me that I did not miss any obvious simpler solution.  I did start with a huge pile og filter, reduce and other higher level function but quickly lost track of what I was actually doing, rendering the code completely unreadable.

Comment: what you could do is to remove the filter statements, and add `row.element.isFree` to the `where` clause for more performance gains.